# Extracting specific variables from XML for use later

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file sourced from the web: http://www.xmlcharts.com/cache/precious-metals.php

I would like to code in PHP the ability to source the following value:

The value for "gold", from "currency" = "aud"
The extracted value needs to be a number that can be manipulated later, such as add to it, divide, etc, for further computation. Also "gold" and "aud" should be variables I can modify elsewhere on the website via input.

Then I need extracted data displayed as such:
"Gold [number to 2 decimal places] [currency in all capital letters]"

I have tried multiple solutions, but nothing seems to be displayed.

Here is the original code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.xmlcharts.com/cache/precious-metals.php'); 

foreach ($xml->currency as $node) {
$attributes = $node->attributes();
$currency = $attributes['access'];
foreach ($node->price as $value) {
$attributes = $value->attributes();
$commodity = $attributes['access'];

$digits = floatval(strval($value));
if (($currency == "aud") && ($commodity == "gold")) {
$goldPrice = round($digits * 31.1034768, 2);
}

if (($currency == "aud") && ($commodity == "silver")) {
$silverPrice = round($digits * 31.1034768, 2);

}



}



}

echo "Gold <span style=\"color: #0E0;\" >" . $goldPrice . "</span> AUD | ";
echo "Silver <span style=\"color: #0E0;\" >" . $silverPrice . "</span> AUD ";
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried

Comment: I updated the feed with the code used.